# Laravel unrequired parameter in request can not be null

Tags: forms, laravel, null, request, required

Hello my problem is that when I post data from form to my controller it bumps up an error saying that my column can not be null.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'date' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`body`, `importance`, `date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (qqqqqq, i_u, , 2018-01-25 22:29:16, 2018-01-25 22:29:16))
```

It seems that this column must be filled but I want it to be optional.
I've tried to make it null as default but it did not work. 
And indeed when the column is filled everything works properly. 
The matter is that I want this input to be filled optionally.

Here is the source plz help.(I guess it is all about the date)

My form

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/planer/public/">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            {{--Describtion of a taks--}}
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
```

```
            {{--Importance--}}
            <div class="form-group  mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="importance">
                    <option value="i_u">Ważne pilne</option>
                    <option value="i_nu">Ważne mniej pilne</option>
                    <option value="ni_u">Mniej ważne pilne</option>
                    <option value="ni_nu">Mniej ważne mniej pilne</option>



                </select>
            </div>

            {{--Date--}}
            <div class="form-group mb-2"> <!-- Date input -->
                <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Day/Month/Hour" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Dodaj</button>

        </form>
```

Routes from web.php

```
Route::get('/','TasksController@index');
```

Route::post('/','TasksController@store');

Route::delete('/{task}','TasksController@destroy');

My table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->string('importance');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And my controller

```
 public function store(){
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'body'=>'required',
        'importance'=>'required'
    ]);

    Task::create([
        'body'=>request('body'),
        'importance'=>request('importance'),
        'date'=>request('date')
    ]);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the code here, instead of images. The tools are all there. Consult the help me section if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must mark a column as `nullable` in your migration if you'd like it to be optional on insert.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->string('importance');
        $table->string('date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The documentation for that is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#column-modifiers

You can modify a column you have already created using the `changes()` method in a migration, e.g:

1. `php artisan make:migration set_date_nullable --table=tasks`
2. Write your migration:

   ```
   Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('date')->nullable()->change();
   });
   ```
3. Run `php artisan migrate`

The documentation for that is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#modifying-columns

P.s: check out the `date` column type, instead of `string`.